# JavaScript setTimeout and Chrome memory utilization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, settimeout, utilization

I am facing a problem with javascript and browser (Chrome) memory utilization.

There is timer (setTimeout) in my script, which is check location from browser. I have noticed that there is gradual increase in memory utilization (in task manger) by this tab which result in max memory among all tabs after some time and eventually page freezes and crashes.

Is there any way or some JS using which I can free memory after some time?

solution :

Before :

```
function recalculateDistance() {
    getLocation();
    getDistance();
    setTimeout("recalculateDistance()", 10000);
}
```

After :

```
var timer = null;

function recalculateDistance() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        getLocation();
        getDistance();
        timer = setTimeout("recalculateDistance()", 10000);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem lies inside the code you're starting in setTimeout(). Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the code, as suggested.

There is `clearTimeout()` for, like the name says, clearing timeouts. This could help you?

And in addition, if you're doing a "timer", I'd suggest using `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`

Comment: If this answer was any help, I'd appreciate upvoting and approving it :)